# How to type annotate a static field of a class that references the same class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-annotation

I am maintaining a collection of created objects within class:

```
class Foo:
    all_of_us: = []

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.all_of_us.append(self)
```

Which fails if I try to type annotate:

```
import typing

class Foo:
    all_of_us: typing.List[Foo] = []
```

With `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`.

What is the right way to go about it?

Comment: The upcoming Python 3.11 will have a `Self` type for this use
https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two choices :

if you are using a recent version of python, you can use the `annotations` module from `__future__` (that will store your annotations directly as strings without having to do it manually)

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List

class Foo:
    all_of_us: List[Foo] = []
```

if you have an older version, simply put our class type inside a string manually:

```
from typing import List

class Foo:
    all_of_us: List['Foo'] = []
```